# Подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

Отец и два родные брата за честь и вольность там легли. Вопрос: 1)Чем выражено подлежащее? 2)Что подлежашее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 2):

Отец и два  брата-два однородных подлежащих, выраженных сущ. и слитным сочетанием числит.+ сущ. в род.пад.

легли - сказуемое.